# Ексель сравнение полей

Tags: excel

Нужна формула. Перерыл все if else, но что то не выходит, возвращает 0 постоянно.
К примеру:
На одном листе Есть строка с определенным значением, на другом есть строка с таким же значением. И нужно сравнить и выдать результат на первом листе. Результат должен быть в соседнем поле первого листа и равен значению соседнего поля второго листа в котором значения первых строк совпадают.

Comment: если http://joxi.ru/MAjxe6Gcx7KeLm эта строка http://joxi.ru/5mdanD0CenVEW2 передать сюда http://joxi.ru/Q2KaqwVCwaJDxr

Answer (score 0):

В `E2` и протянуть вниз:

```
=ВПР(D2;Лист2!$A$2:$B$999;2;)
```

Если искомого может не быть, то желательно обойти возможную ошибку:

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ВПР(D2;Лист2!$A$2:$B$999;2;);"нет")
```

Comment: меняю название листа "Лист2" на "M1A" (так как у меня такое название листа 2) передает просто значение "ИСТИНА", а не значение соседнего поля, нужно именно числовое значение соседнего поля с второго листа

Comment: Что-то не так сделали или не так объяснили. Покажите пример, где ошибка

Comment: Показал по скринам, что и куда должно идти. Посмотрите скрины

Comment: Формула написана по этим рисункам

Comment: http://joxi.ru/KAxWM1Vt1LEnQ2

Comment: Должно быть в привычке: если после получения подсказки не получилось - сначала справку по функции читать, потом уже спрашивать... У Вас диапазон поиска - только строка 5000.